# Nexus repository consuming 100 cpu usage?

Tags: nexus

we have setup nexus repository version 3 in window machine.But it is consuming 100 percent CPU usage. In that machine we have installed Jenkins and Gitblit as well.
can you please let me know how to resolve this issue.